# merge columns separated by commas in R

Tags: r, merge, multiple-columns

I have a table with many columns in which I would like to merge all the text in columns into the first one. Like this

| ID | A | B | C | etc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aa | bb | cc |  |
| 2 | ai | ao | au |  |

into

| ID | A | B | C | etc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | aa,bb,cc |  |  |  |
| 2 | ai,ao,au |  |  |  |

The problem is the amount of columns, since I can't write their name one by one.

Can you help me?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try: `data.frame(x[1], A=do.call(function(...) paste(..., sep=","), x[-1]))`

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)

bind_cols(df[1],df %>% rowwise() %>% transmute(A = toString(c_across(cols = -ID))))
  ID          A
1  1 aa, bb, cc
2  2 ai, ao, au
```

Data used:

```
df
  ID  A  B  C
1  1 aa bb cc
2  2 ai ao au
```

Answer (score 0):

There will be a better way to do this, but here's a quick way that works and is easily adapted to your specific needs.

```
df  <-  data.frame(ID = c(1,2),
                   A = c("aa","ai"),
                   B = c("bb","ao"),
                   C = c("cc", "au"))

for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  df$A[i]  <- paste0(df[i,2:ncol(df)], collapse = ",")  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df %>%
  tidyr::unite(col = "unitedcol", A:C, sep = ",")
```